# Repeating elements in a dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Hi all I have the following dataframe:

```
A | B | C
1   2   3 
2   3   4 
3   4   5
4   5   6
```

And I am trying to only repeat the last two rows of the data so that it looks like this:

```
A | B | C
1   2   3 
2   3   4 
3   4   5
3   4   5
4   5   6
4   5   6
```

I have tried using append, concat and repeat to no avail.

```
repeated = lambda x:x.repeat(2)
df.append(df[-2:].apply(repeated),ignore_index=True)
```

This returns the following dataframe, which is incorrect:

```
A | B | C
1   2   3 
2   3   4 
3   4   5
4   5   6
3   4   5
3   4   5
4   5   6
4   5   6
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`numpy.repeat`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html) for repeating index and then create `df1` by [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html), last append to original, but before filter out last 2 rows by [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html):

```
df1 = df.loc[np.repeat(df.index[-2:].values, 2)]
print (df1)
   A  B  C
2  3  4  5
2  3  4  5
3  4  5  6
3  4  5  6

print (df.iloc[:-2])
   A  B  C
0  1  2  3
1  2  3  4

df = df.iloc[:-2].append(df1,ignore_index=True)
print (df)
   A  B  C
0  1  2  3
1  2  3  4
2  3  4  5
3  3  4  5
4  4  5  6
5  4  5  6
```

If want use your code add `iloc` for filtering only last 2 rows:

```
repeated = lambda x:x.repeat(2)
df = df.iloc[:-2].append(df.iloc[-2:].apply(repeated),ignore_index=True)
print (df)
   A  B  C
0  1  2  3
1  2  3  4
2  3  4  5
3  3  4  5
4  4  5  6
5  4  5  6
```

Comment: thanks for the comment! I may have confused you however, I am trying to return the output of the second dataframe I posted. I will edit the question to reflect that

Comment: thanks! so just to clarify, what your code is doing is creating a new dataframe with the repeated values, and then modifying the original dataframe by slicing out the last two rows and appending the new dataframe?

Comment: you seem to be very knowledgeable on pandas and python, how can I better improve my knowledge as well?

Comment: I think very nice tutorial is [modern pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/tutorials.html#modern-pandas), but mainly T learn from another users in SO.

Comment: @codeninja you can also consider up-voting the answer you accepted.

Answer (score 2):

Use `pd.concat` and index slicing with `.iloc`:

```
pd.concat([df,df.iloc[-2:]]).sort_values(by='A')
```

Output:

```
   A  B  C
0  1  2  3
1  2  3  4
2  3  4  5
2  3  4  5
3  4  5  6
3  4  5  6
```

Comment: Thanks! However when I tried to sort by the column, my index values were out of wack, making the dataframe jumbled. Any suggestions?

Comment: Are your index important?  If not, you can reset_index(), if so, then you need to either sort by index or by columns.  I think.

Comment: @piRSquared  Thank you and thank you for the reduction suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

I'm partial to manipulating the index into the pattern we are aiming for then asking the dataframe to take the new form.

**Option 1**
Use [**`pd.DataFrame.reindex`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html)

```
df.reindex(df.index[:-2].append(df.index[-2:].repeat(2)))

   A  B  C
0  1  2  3
1  2  3  4
2  3  4  5
2  3  4  5
3  4  5  6
3  4  5  6
```

Same thing in multiple lines

```
i = df.index
idx = i[:-2].append(i[-2:].repeat(2))
df.reindex(idx)
```

Could also use `loc`

```
i = df.index
idx = i[:-2].append(i[-2:].repeat(2))
df.loc[idx]
```

---

**Option 2**
Reconstruct from `values`.  Only do this is all `dtypes` are the same.

```
i = np.arange(len(df))
idx = np.append(i[:-2], i[-2:].repeat(2))
pd.DataFrame(df.values[idx], df.index[idx])

   0  1  2
0  1  2  3
1  2  3  4
2  3  4  5
2  3  4  5
3  4  5  6
3  4  5  6
```

---

**Option 3**
Can also use `np.array` in `iloc`

```
i = np.arange(len(df))
idx = np.append(i[:-2], i[-2:].repeat(2))
df.iloc[idx]

   A  B  C
0  1  2  3
1  2  3  4
2  3  4  5
2  3  4  5
3  4  5  6
3  4  5  6
```